# Calculator windows 10 but missing MC, M+, M-, MU and MR buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I actually don't know how these buttons (MC, M+, M-, MU and MR) work and how to operate them without using lambda function I would like to ask for some help so I can upgrade it to actually be 100% similar to the Windows 10 Calculator.

Here is my code any help will me so much:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

full_stop = 1
for_calculation = None


def button(parent, text, font, bg, width, pad=1):
    btn = Button(parent, text=text, font=font, bg=bg, width=width, height=2, relief=FLAT, bd=0, padx=pad)
    return btn



def zero(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "0")


# num 1
def one(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "1")


# num 2
def two(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "2")


# num 3
def three(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "3")


# num 4
def four(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "4")


# num 5
def five(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "5")


# num 6
def six(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "6")


# num 7
def seven(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "7")


# num 8
def eight(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "8")


# num 9
def nine(event=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + "9")



# add func
def add(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "+")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "+")
        full_stop = 1


# subtract func
def subtract(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "-")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "-")
        full_stop = 1


# multiply fuc
def multiply(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "x")
        full_stop = 1


def percent(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "%")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "%")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "%")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "%")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "%")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "%")
        else:
            expression.set(int(expression.get())/100)
        full_stop = 1


# divide func
def divide(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "÷")
        else:
            expression.set(expression.get() + "÷")
        full_stop = 1



def over(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "1/x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "1/x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "1/x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "1/x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "1/x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "1/x")
        else:
            expression.set(1/int(expression.get()))
        full_stop = 1

def power(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x²")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x²")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x²")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x²")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x²")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x²")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x²"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "x²")
        else:
            expression.set(math.pow(int(expression.get()),2))
        full_stop = 1

def sqr(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and not expression.get().endswith("."):
        if expression.get().endswith("+"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("-"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("÷"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("%"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("1/x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("x²"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        elif expression.get().endswith("√x"):
            expression.set(expression.get()[:-1] + "√x")
        else:
            expression.set(math.sqrt(int(expression.get())))
        full_stop = 1


def point(event=""):
    global full_stop
    if len(expression.get()) < 30 and full_stop == 1:
        if not expression.get().endswith(("+", "-", "x", "%","÷", "1/x","x²")):
            expression.set(expression.get() + ".")
            full_stop = 0





def reverse():
    if not expression.get().startswith("-") and not expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set("-" + expression.get())
    elif expression.get().startswith("-"):
        expression.set(expression.get()[1:])



def delete(event=""):
    expression.set(expression.get()[:-1])
    if expression.get() == "":
        expression.set("0")



def reset(event=""):
    global for_calculation
    expression.set("0")
    for_calculation = None
    calculated.set("")


# THIS FUNCTION WILL CALCULATE THE RESULT OF THE EXPRESSION
def calculate(event=""):
    global for_calculation
    for_calculation = expression.get().replace("x", "*").replace("÷", "/")
    calculated.set(eval(for_calculation))
    if str(calculated.get()[int(len(calculated.get()) - 2):]) == ".0":
        calculated.set(calculated.get()[:-2])
    expression.set("0")


root = Tk()
root.title("CALCULATOR")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.configure(bg="#D9D9D9")



expression = StringVar(root, "0")
calculated = StringVar(root)

expression_txt = Entry(root, textvariable=expression, justify=RIGHT, selectbackground="#D9D9D9",
                       font="Comic-sens 15 bold", selectforeground="#000000", readonlybackground="#D9D9D9", relief=FLAT,
                       bd=0, state="readonly")
expression_txt.pack(pady=5, anchor=N, padx=2, fill=X)


calculated_lbl = Label(root, textvariable=calculated, anchor=E, bg="#D9D9D9", relief=FLAT, bd=0,
                       font="Comic-sens 20 bold")
calculated_lbl.pack(pady=5, anchor=N, padx=6, fill=X)


frame1 = Frame(root, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame1, "%", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=percent)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame1, "CE", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=reset)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)


btn = button(frame1, "C", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=delete)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn= button(frame1, "<-", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=delete)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)


frame1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


frame2 = Frame(root, bg="#D9D9D9")


btn = button(frame2,"1/x","Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=over)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "x²","Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=power)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "√x","Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=sqr)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame2, "÷", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=divide)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

frame2.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


frame3 = Frame(root, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame3, "7", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=seven)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "8", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=eight)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "9", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=nine)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame3, "x", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=multiply)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

frame3.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


frame4 = Frame(root, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame4, "4", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=four)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "5", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=five)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "6", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=six)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame4, "-", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=subtract)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

frame4.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


frame5 = Frame(root, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame5, "1", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=one)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame5, "2", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=two)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame5, "3", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=three)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame5, "+", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=add)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

frame5.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


frame6 = Frame(root, bg="#D9D9D9")

btn = button(frame6, "±", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=reverse)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame6, "0", "Calibri 15 bold", "#FFFFFF", 10)
btn.config(command=zero)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame6, ".", "Calibri 15", "#EEEEEE", 10)
btn.config(command=point)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

btn = button(frame6, "=", "Calibri 15 bold", "#D9D9D9", 10)
btn.config(command=calculate)
btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1, fill=BOTH)

frame6.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, fill=BOTH)


root.bind('0', zero)
root.bind('1', one)
root.bind('2', two)
root.bind('3', three)
root.bind('4', four)
root.bind('5', five)
root.bind('6', six)
root.bind('7', seven)
root.bind('8', eight)
root.bind('9', nine)
root.bind('+', add)
root.bind('-', subtract)
root.bind('*', multiply)
root.bind('/', divide)
root.bind('.', point)
root.bind('%', percent)
root.bind("1/x", over)
root.bind('<BackSpace>', delete)
root.bind('<Delete>', reset)
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)


root.mainloop()
```

I have been doing a python app for a calculator with Tkinter. I want to know how access the buttons properties such as their size, height, width , etc. but i am trying to avoid lambda for me to learn slowly.

Comment: Search about `cget()`.

Comment: I get how `cget()` works but I need to know how to operate it with these buttons

Comment: Please reduce this down to a [mcve]. There is a lot of code that seems unnecessary to illustrate the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about functions that use memory, so you need to implement storage for the memorized value :

```
full_stop = 1
for_calculation = None
memory = None
```

- When M+ is pressed you add the current term of the operation (the 'visible' value) to the memory (or you replace the initial None by the new value).
- When the M- is pressed you subtract the current term from the memory (or replace the initial None by a negative number).
- With MR you recall the memory, meaning that you replace the current term by the
  memorized value.
- With MC you clear the memory replacing its current value by None.

The MU key is little bit more complex, here is a [link](http://eatonfamily.net.au/calculator-mu-key/) explaining what it does.

I'm not sure but it's possible that a variable storing the current term (the 'visible' value) is missing in your current implementation. In that case you should add one to avoid extracting the term from the whole expression each time you need it.

Finally, you could shorten your codes by making common what can be, as for instance :

```
def num(stringNumber, even=""):
    if expression.get().startswith("0") and len(expression.get()) == 1:
        expression.set("")
    if len(expression.get()) < 30:
        expression.set(expression.get() + stringNumber)

def zero(even=""): num("0", even)
def one(even=""): num("1", even)
def two(even=""): num("2", even)
#and so on
```

Comment: Thank you soo much will try to shorten everything and add the missing buttons